# Live video stream from Android to server , pc and, android device

Tags: java, android

I'm going to do my final project on android video streaming ,so i need your help guys.
 actually i want to send Live video streaming from Android to server , pc and, android device. Can any body refer to similar **code** or doc. related to this topic. I'll appreciate that.

  +

Comment: Use sourceforge or google first, then ask a complete question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a `UPnP` server.
http://teleal.org/projects/cling

Open Source DLNA/UPnP stack, libraries, and tools for Java and Android developers